# Names of Objects properties vs Constructor function arguments in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

First of all, I apologize if this question is too basic or not worded correctly. I'm learning JavaScript and I'm still new to it. And I've been trying to figure out an example that is included in a textbook, and need some help.

This is the example:

```
var star = new Object;

function Star(constell, type, specclass, magnitude) {
  this.constellation = constell;
  this.type = type;
  this.spectralClass = specclass;
  this.mag = magnitude;
}

star["Polaris"] = new Star("Ursa Minor", "Double", "F7", 2.0);
alert(star["Polaris"].spectralClass);
```

The part that I don't get here (and can't seem to find an explanation) is that when I pick a random object to alert such as

```
alert(star["Polaris"].spectralClass);
```

I have to use the name inside a function aka `spectralClass` and not `specclass`. Why is that? Why not just use `specclass` if I already assigned it to `spectralClass`? I'm missing a huge chunk of knowledge here, I assume, but I just can't seem to figure out what it is.

Thank you!

Comment: Please put the alert right where you intend it to run in the example above; thanks.

Comment: `specclass` is a local variable inside the constructor function. `spectralClass` is the name of the property exposed by the constructor. Although I would be very wary of anything your book says if it seriously uses `var star = new Object;` instead of `var star = {};`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol consider writing an answer?

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol It gives both of those examples var star = new Object; and var star = {}; as a way to create a new object. :D But thank you for pointing it out. And thank you for the explanation, I'm starting to make sense of it. And yup, it's definitely an answer to the question! :)

Comment: You might not want to alert an object as it will output `[object Object]`. Maybe use `console.log` instead?

Comment: Yeah, fair enough, dunno why I commented when it's an answer XD Posted the answer part below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's simplify the code even further:

```
function Star(specclass) {
    this.spectralClass = specclass;
}
```

Here, `Star` is a *constructor* function. It takes one argument, which can be referred to via the name `specclass` *inside the function.*

The function assigns this argument value to the object's property named `spectralClass`.

Now,

```
var polarisStar = new Star("F7");
```

`polarisStar` is the object constructed by the `Star` function, which has assigned the value of `"F7"` to the object's `spectralClass` property. So you can access it via `polarisStar.spectralClass`, e.g.

```
alert(polarisStar.spectralClass);
```

---

Actually, it's a common practice to give constructor's arguments and constructed object's properties the same name, i.e.:

```
function Star(spectralClass) {
    this.spectralClass = spectralClass;
}
```

This makes the code it a little bit more readable.

Comment: Ok, wow! Now I get it! Thank you so much for this detailed explanation and for a common practice bit, too. Really appreciate it! This makes things much easier and logical.

Comment: @ hemoglobin I'm glad that I could help; @chazsolo yes of course, fixed that, thank you very much for the noticing this.

Answer (score 3):

`specclass` is a local variable inside the constructor function.
`spectralClass` is the name of the property exposed by the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that:

```
this.spectralClass
```

is in the constructor makes the variable available to that objects instance... So you can access it in other functions within the class.

On the other hand,

```
specclass
```

Is only local to the constructor function.